# Как растянуть текст на всю высоту?

Tags: css, css3, html5

Здравствуйте!
Есть блок, в котором может быть минимум 1 предложение текста.
Блок может иметь любую высоту и ширину.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 1vh 1vw;
  font-size: calc(3vw + 3vh);
  line-height: 1.5;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века.</p>
</div>
```

Как растянуть текст на всю высоту(если это возможно на css)?
Текста также может быть много, который должен уменьшаться пропорционально взависимости от размера блока.

Варианты на `js(jquery)` не предлагайте, т.к решение на `js` есть.

Спасибо

Answer (score 3):

Есть один костыльный способ нужно узнать кол-во строк и поделить их на высоту экрана. Но а если серьезно то без javascript как мне кажется по-другому никак.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 1vh 1vw;
  font-size: calc(3vw + 3vh);
  line-height: calc(100vh / 4);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Вы бы хоть проверяли свои ответы, прежде чем их публиковать...